# ASP.NET simple custom control with two way binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, data-binding

I have custom control with two textboxes and one drop down list. I want to make it two-way data bound, so when I put it into ie. Details View control like this:

```
    <asp:MyCustomControl ID="MyId" runat="server" Value1='<%# Bind("val1") %>'>
    </asp:MyCustomControl>
```

then it should work like regular TextBox..

In my control I have `Value1` defined:

```
    [
    Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay),
    Browsable(true),
    DefaultValue(0),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)
    ]
    public  double Value1
    {
        get
        {
            if(ViewState["Value1"]==null)
                return 0;
            return (double)ViewState["Value1"];                
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["Value1"] = value;
        }
    }
```

I want this control to keep simple.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should take a look at [Developing Custom Data-Bound Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366539.aspx#Y4342) - when it comes to two-way databound control, I'm not sure if there's such a thing as simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some kind of workaround. The property in control (ascx.cs) now looks like this:

```
    private double _value = 0;
    [
    Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay),
    Browsable(true),
    DefaultValue(0),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)
    ]
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            double d = 0;
            Double.TryParse(ValueControlTextBox.Text,out d);
            return d;
        }
        set
        {   
            ValueControlTextBox.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", value);
            _value = value;
        }
    }
```

And that works as I need.