# How can I create a WebControl in ASP.NET that has public properties tied to the input elements of a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-controls

In short, I want to create a WebControl that may appear multiple times in an input form.  The WebControl I've drafted out has properties that are assumed to be related to the values in the web control (text boxes etc.)  What I want to be able to do is access the contents of the WebControl's input elements by name in my submit handler as below:

```
var firstname = customControl.FirstName;
var lastname = customControl.LastName;
```

I come from a WPF background so this is just familiar enough I am getting myself into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off the top of my head (just getting back to .NET after a few months on other languages), and I'm assuming it's for a User control because Server controls are pretty well documented for properties.

First, assume your user control has textboxes `txtFirst` and `txtLast`.

In the code-behind, add public properties FirstName and LastName. The properties would look like this:

```
public string FirstName {
 get { return this.txtFirst.Text.Trim(); }
 set { this.txtFirst.Text = value ?? ""; }
}

public string LastName {
 get { return this.txtLast.Text.Trim(); }
 set { this.txtLast.Text = value ?? ""; }
}
```

That's it. My apologies if you weren't asking about a user control.

Comment: What is the best way of adding those composite controls?

Comment: Also one sample I found indicated that it was a good idea to use ViewState?

 get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["StartDate"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["StartDate"] = value;
            }

Comment: @Firoso - as for "adding those composite controls", I'm not quite sure what you mean. As for view state, you can definitely use it. As a mattter of fact, that's how I normally do it. But in this case I think you wanted to base the values on the textboxes so why not store them there? They'll be available to the containing form in postback. If you have a value that's not represented in a visual control then you definitely have to use view state, and the example you gave looks right.

Comment: @Firoso - just occurred to me: if by "adding those composite controls" you meant how do you get them onto your ASPX page, you'll find that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab(v=vs.100).aspx). I have to look it up (either online or existing code) every time I add; it's a tiny bit of markup but I can never quite commit it to memory :)

Comment: I meant more along the lines of how do I add txtLast/txtFirst to the rendering of customControl ;-)

Comment: is it enough to just new up a bunch of objects in CreateChildControls and use Controls.Add?

Comment: Yes - you can instantiate the objects in `CreateChildControls`. You'll need to override the ancestor method. But based on these last two comments it looks like you're creating a "Server" control rather than a "User" control. My answer was for a User control. The MSDN MSDN topic [Developing Custom ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy(v=vs.100).aspx) has lots of examples, with [Composite Web Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3257x3ea(v=vs.100).aspx) probably being the best for your situation. It includes property examples.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is?

Comment: No worries - I think everyone starts off not knowing the difference, then they figure it out, then they forget they never knew :). Here's my best shot: a "User" control is mostly written in design mode and will have an ascx extension with associated code-behind files. A "Server" control is a C# class, written by heads-down coding. Server control pros: more flexibility; can be used in multiple projects. Server control cons: usually take longer to develop so often not worth it for one-offs. User control pros: quick development. User control cons: can't be reused in other projects.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance.  LAST QUESTION I SWEAR! Assuming I am using a UserControl, and assuming I do implement ViewState backed properties, and assuming this control is meant to be used in a form, how should I go about "wiring up" the control so that the text of something like "nameTextBox" is "bound" to "Name property? I'm still a little fuzzy on view state and postbacks with regards to forms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26114/discussion-between-firoso-and-graceemile)

Comment: Asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393525/how-can-i-connect-up-my-usercontrol-properties-in-such-a-way-that-they-retain-st

Comment: Sorry @Firoso, I was out of the office for a while there. I'm afraid I don't have time for a chat today; I'd be happy to try one tomorrow if you still need help. I'm generally available 9:00AM - 6:00AM US Eastern Time. I'll post something about databinding in a minute.

Comment: I've never done data binding with a User control, but it looks like it's supported. Check out this [StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194364/asp-net-simple-custom-control-with-two-way-binding). In the answer the get/set is like the code I initially put up in that it uses the control (in this case a textbox) to persist. The difference is the `Bindable(...)]` attribute right above the property. If you have a value that's not related to a control then View State is definitely the way to go, but for data binding I'd recommend using the control.