# How can I connect up my UserControl properties in such a way that they retain state on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-controls

In an ASP.NET Webforms application I have a submission form containing a UserControl with properties as such:

```
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["Name"];
            return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["Name"] = value;
        }
    }
```

This is adapted from an MSDN walk-through.  This is assumed to be "bound" (not databinding as I don't think that's possible) to the contents of a text box defined in the ascx as below:

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="name" />
```

The question is, what is the best practice for allowing this to be accessible as a public property, and retain state on postback?

Comment: By default, TextBox control persists data unless you intentionally turn off the view state. Am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, so how SHOULD I go about doing this in a UserControl

Comment: I think you're missing that this usercontrol is composed of many textboxes, and each one needs to have it's text contents exposed as a property on the usercontrol.

Comment: Anything wrong with simply exposing the `Text` property of each `TextBox` control? `public string Name { get { return name.Text; } set { name.Text = value; } }`

Comment: seems to work Richard, care to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest option is to have the public properties on your `UserControl` delegate to the properties of the child controls:

```
public string Name
{
   get { return name.Text; }
   set { name.Text = value; }
}
```

The `TextBox` will then take care of maintaining the state on postback.

Comment: The TextBox maintaining postback state was the missing element, thank you!